# How to check if two strings are on the same line when reading from a .txt file

Tags: python

I am trying to make a notepad program, where you need to sign in first to read the notes you made previously.

During registration, the usernames are saved onto "Usernames.txt", the passwords on "Passwords.txt".To validate whether the username matches up with the password, I want to check whether the line that a certain username is on is the same as the line where is the password that goes with the username is located.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why are you using while loops instead of if statements? sure, in this case they do the same thing, but why

Comment: Because, if I used "if", "elif", "else" etc., it would just output it once. If the user does not meet the requirements stated by the program more than once, it will just ignore it if you use "if".

Comment: yes, but things like `while username in open("Usernames.txt").read():` will always only execute once. Also, your question isn't really clear, could you try rephrasing it?

Comment: Yes, but you should use a single `while True` with many `if` inside, at least one of those `if` leading to a `break`.

Comment: @TilmanB.akaNerdyyy no, he's reading username again inside the loop.

Comment: The code you provided seems irrelevant to what seems to be your real question. See how to create a [mcve], and please edit your question with a clear example of what you want to accomplish, the relevant part of the code, and the exact problem you've run into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open both files and iterate them simultaneously:

```
with open('username.txt') as users, open('password.txt') as passwds:
    for user, passwd in zip(users, passwds):
        # Check username/password here
```

However, this isn't a very good storage layout; if you experience any errors reading or writing the files your authentication database can become corrupt and one user could end up with another user's password.

You'd be much better to store both properties in a single file. JSON or even CSV would be acceptable, but using the built in `sqlite3` module would be best.

Answer (score 0):

I will not comment on your code, but I'll focus on this aspect only:

> I want to check whether the line that a certain username is on is the
>   same as the line where is the password that goes with the username is
>   located.

```
# Open the users file, read its content.
u = open("Usernames.txt","a+")
all_users = u.readlines()

# Compare each line with the username you are looking for.
user_to_find = "Sam"
line_where_user_was_found = None

for n,user in enumerate(all_users):
    if user == user_to_find:
        line_where_user_was_found = n
        break

# Open the passwords file, read its content.
p = open("Passwords.txt","a+")
all_passwords = p.readlines()

# Compare each lines with the password you are looking for.
password_to_find = "1234"
line_where_password_was_found = None

for m,password in enumerate(all_passwords):
    if password == password_to_find :
        line_where_password_was_found = m
        break

# Check if the username-password pair matches.
does_it_match = (line_where_user_was_found == line_where_password_was_found)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Both `line_where_password_was_found` and `line_where_user_was_found` is always valued at "None", meaning, if you have a valid username, there is no password - everything is "True".

Comment: Yeah because it is an example. I'm sure you don't have a user called Sam with his password being 1234. You have to replace those with whatever you want to look for, for example something created by `input()`.

Comment: This would fail if two users have the same password, as the line number of the first occurence of the password would be returned in both cases. Also, note that there is an `index` method that does what you do in your loops.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative method, I avoided `index` here because it also some a more complex to handle the `ValueError` you get when the element is not in the list.

Comment: Regarding the failing when two users have the same password, that is on OP's definiion of matching user/password not on me.

Answer (score 0):

You can read a file's lines into a list:

```
with open("Usernames.txt") as f:
    usernames = f.readlines()
```

And you can get the line number of a particular string with `index`:

```
ix = usernames.index(username)
```

And you can of course get the password at that index by reading the password file into another list and looking at `passwords[ix]`.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you want:

```
# Get login credentials from user and cast from unicode to string
username = str(raw_input("username:"))
password = str(raw_input("password:"))

# Get all valid usernames as a list and remove newlines from end
with open("Usernames.txt") as usernameFile:
    usernameList = [line.replace("\n", "") for line in usernameFile.readlines()]

# Get all valid passwords as a list and remove newlines from end
with open("Passwords.txt") as passwordFile:
    passwordList = [line.replace("\n", "") for line in passwordFile.readlines()]

# Figure out which lines the user's username and password are on
lineOfUsername = -2
lineOfPassword = -1
try:
    lineOfUsername = usernameList.index(username)
    lineOfPassword = passwordList.index(password)
# If either is not found, inform the user
except ValueError:
    print("Bad username or password")
    exit()

# If the lines match, then you got there!
if(lineOfUsername == lineOfPassword):
    # Your logic here
    print("Valid login")
# Otherwise, you didn't (womp, womp)
else:
    print("Bad username or password")
```

A few caveats:

- This is horrible for security. As in, this is not a security solution. If you wonder why, look up the subject on computerphile on YouTube.
- If the either the username or password have dups, that is not accounted for here. And really can't be, given the parameters of your question.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't seem to be working. The usernames don't seem to be _in_ the list.

Comment: All the lines you get with `readlines` end with a`\n`, while `username` and `password` don't, so there won't be a match. Also, you should take into account the possibility of duplicate passwords - and using `index` prevents that.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Good catch on the newlines. Also, I did mention the dup issue in my post: "If the either the username or password have dups, that is not accounted for here. And really can't be, given the parameters of your question." I will update my code to handle newlines.

Comment: @sombat92 I updated my solution (this time testing my code in an editor, like a boss). Try again, if you dare.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code:

```
username_to_check = "john"
password_to_check = "1234"

file_usernames = open('usernames_filepath_here')
file_passwords = open('passwords_filepath_here')

usernames = file_usernames.read().splitlines()
passwords = file_passwords.read().splitlines()

login_succeed = False
for i in range(0, len(usernames)):
    if usernames[i] == username_to_check and passwords[i] == password_to_check:
        login_succeed = True

print(login_succeed)
```

Comment: It seems to be only false.

Comment: Yes, but it always says that my login is invalid.